# std::map::lower_bound is generating core dump for map key greater than 2000

Tags: c++, algorithm, stdmap

For the below sample program, the lower_bound is generating core dump. Any idea where could be the mistake ?

Also, can anyone please explain how the lower_bound and upper_bound algorithm works in c++?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main ()
{
  std::map<int,int> mymap;
  std::map<int,int>::iterator itlow,itup;

  mymap[100]=10;
  mymap[1000]=20;
  mymap[2000]=40;
  mymap[3000]=60;
  mymap[4000]=80;
  mymap[5000]=100;

  itlow=mymap.lower_bound (2001);
  itup=mymap.upper_bound (1500);

  std::cout<<(itlow->first)<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<(itup->first)<<std::endl;
  mymap.erase(itlow,itup);        // erases [itlow,itup)

  // print content:
  for (std::map<int,int>::iterator it=mymap.begin(); it!=mymap.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: As for how the algorithms work: for their interface, consult a [suitable reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound). How they work internally: the map is (most likely) a binary search tree, so finding such bounds is standard traversal of such a tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the erase backwards:

```
mymap.erase(itup, itlow);        // erases [itlow,itup)
```

You can erase only from a smaller iterator to a iterator following the first parameter. In this case your iterators point to the values:

```
lower: 3000
upper: 2000
and itup < itlow
```

from [lower_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/) and [upper_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/)

`lower_bound` returns:

> Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range
>   [first,last) which does not compare less than val.

`upper_bound` returns:

> Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range
>   [first,last) which compares greater than val.

Comment: Thanks. I found the reason of the crash.